# Dynamic form -  DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where new input fields can be added via an `add` link. Each newly added input field can also be removed via a `remove` link.

What can I do so that the `add and remove` link is only shown for the input field that was added last?

Example: [jsfiddle - my code](http://jsfiddle.net/4BnHy/)

```
$(function() {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
        var newDiv = $($class).find('div:first').clone();
        //alert(newDiv)                
        newDiv.append('<a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a>')
        newDiv.find('input').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $($class + ':first div:last').before(newDiv);
        $(this).prev('a.add_input').remove();
        alert(ok)
    });

    $('a.remove_input').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to make your problem easier to understand. Feel free to rollback or edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all but the last `.add_input` from the collection:

```
$(this).closest('.find_input').find('.add_input:not(:last)').remove();
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my edit... the `add` link should be shown only at the last element... sorry for the confusion :-/

Comment: @Melissa: @Tatu just got it the wrong way round (maybe because of me). It should give you the right idea though. Obviously, this removes all `add` links instead of the last one. You want all `remove` links to be removed so instead of `.add_input` you have to use `.remove_input`...

Comment: i want add and remove link is only shown for the input field that was added last, and other input() only have remove

Comment: @Melissa: Yes. Tatu showed you the right direction, I showed you the last step. It is all there. You just have to put it together which is not difficult anymore. Of course you have to try to understand the solution and not just copy and paste, otherwise you don't learn anything.